# Without status bar in our swift app

Tags: statusbar

Client request the app with no status bar. Without having the status bar, is there any problem will arise when notification is received while using the app?

Comment: In your .plist add this two keys

1. Status bar is initially hidden -> YES
2. View controller-based status bar appearance -> NO

this ll works for me everytime in swift & in objective-c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .plist add this two keys

[image]

this ll works for me everytime in swift & in objective-c.